# Issue using "having" in Magento collection

Tags: admin, collection, grid, grid-serlization

I am trying to build a custom collection for a grid in Magento admin module. I have created a new collection method  called "addAttributeHaving" which just does the following:

```
public function addAttributeHaving($value)
{
    $this->getSelect()->having($value);
    return $this;
}
```

See collection code:

```
$collection->addFieldToSelect(
    array(
        'entity_id',
        'created_at',
        'increment_id',
        'customer_email',
        'customer_firstname',
        'customer_lastname',
        'grand_total',
        'status'
    )
);

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfop' => 'sales_flat_order_payment'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfop.parent_id', 'sfop.amount_authorized');
$collection->getSelect()->columns('sum(sfop.amount_authorized) AS AUTHD');
$collection->getSelect()->columns('grand_total - sum(sfop.amount_authorized) AS DIF_AU');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.state', array('in' => array('new','payment_review')));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.sd_order_type', array('neq' => 7));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sfop.method', array('neq' => 'giftcard'));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('gt' => $this->getFilterDate()));
$collection->getSelect()->group(array('main_table.entity_id'));
$collection->addAttributeHaving('DIF_AU <> 0');
$collection->load(true,true);

$this->setCollection($collection);
```

This produces the following SQL which executes perfectly fine and produces the expected results when ran outside of Magento.

> `` [METHOD=Varien_Data_Collection_Db->printLogQuery] SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`created_at`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`customer_email`, `main_table`.`customer_firstname`, `main_table`.`customer_lastname`, `main_table`.`grand_total`, `main_table`.`status`, `sfop`.`amount_authorized`, sum(sfop.amount_authorized) AS `AUTHD`, grand_total - sum(sfop.amount_authorized) AS `DIF_AU` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table`
>    LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` AS `sfop` ON main_table.entity_id = sfop.parent_id WHERE (main_table.state in ('new', 'payment_review')) AND (main_table.sd_order_type != 7) AND (sfop.method != 'giftcard') AND (main_table.created_at > '2013-04-07') GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` HAVING (DIF_AU <> 0) ``

However, when I try to load the grid inside Magento I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DIF_AU' in 'having clause'

Additionally, if I remove the having clause (which breaks my results), I am able to use the DIF_AU column for a datasource in the Grid.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to track down the issue to the parent getSelectCountSql() method. This is actually where the issue is happening when trying to get the collection count.

Comment: Post an answer! WTH is that `sd_order_type` coming from?

Comment: Top secret custom order type stuff that has been added to flat tables. I am still working out the answer.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." (solution to come in 7 hours).

Comment: **Someone give this man an upvote**

Comment: Haha… done @benmarks lol ;)

Answer (score 12):

I am going to actually answer my own question here. I know, tacky, but I stumbled upon the answer when looking much closer at the actual stack trace. The collection is loading fine however, the failure comes a little later in execution when we try to get the collection count in **Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSelectCountSql()**. The SQL that is produced from this is:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_flat_order AS main_table LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_payment AS sfop ON main_table.entity_id = sfop.parent_id WHERE (main_table.state in ('payment_review')) AND (main_table.sd_order_type != 7) AND (sfop.method != 'giftcard') AND (main_table.created_at > '2013-04-07') GROUP BY main_table.entity_id HAVING (DIF_AU <> 0)`

You will notice that the HAVING statement is attached yet we have no definition for the DIF_AU column any longer. It appears as though I will need to extend a custom getSelectCountSql() in my collection class to get the right record count.

I have created an extended getSelectCountSql() in the custom collection class that adds back in the missing column required for the having statement.

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
  {
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->columns('grand_total - sum(sfop.amount_authorized) AS DIF_AU');
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    return $countSelect;
  }
```

Comment: Not tacky at all… if you figure out the solution first, it's encouraged. Others will potentially find it helpful down the road. +1 :)

Comment: You should file a bug report! http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking

Comment: This is an issue I have also seen, and well done on finding an answer. However, I do not think your solution is correct - because you are using group by, your SelectCountSql needs to be returning the number of groups. So you need either a count(fetchAll()), or to rewrite your query using `count(distinct main_table.entity_id)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: I think you are very likely correct. This project has been on the back burner since this posting, and just now getting back to it. In a demo last week, I noticed incorrect record count being reported in the grid. Will report back my findings once I have resolved it.

Comment: @AnthonyLeachJr any news on your findings?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);` means it will reset `HAVING` from your collection. That means it will remove the having clause. And Its not what you want. You may want to add it to the collection (`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php->_getSelectCountSql()` here.)

But the main culprit it the `getSize()` method which exists in `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` file.

> I tried the above solution mentioned by @Anthony but that didnt work.

Now i did the below.

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        //$sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $sql = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

Check i am not even using the `getSelectCountSql()`. I am just reading the whole **SQL QUERY** and **fetching all data** and **return the count** of it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue here:
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php:943
add this: $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);

Just copy 
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
to
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php

My code looks now like this:

```
/**
 * Build clear select
 *
 * @param Varien_Db_Select $select
 * @return Varien_Db_Select
 */
protected function _buildClearSelect($select = null)
{
    if (is_null($select)) {
        $select = clone $this->getSelect();
    }
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This solution will work if your select has unique columns names because any columns in the subquery select list must have unique 
>   names

[Subquery: table subquery allows duplicate column names](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6709)

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $select = clone $this->getSelect();
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);        

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset();
    $countSelect->from(array('a' => $select), 'COUNT(*)');
    return $countSelect;
}
```

> PS: This answer is for general magento collections. not related to
>   only product collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        //$sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $sql = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```