# How to add dynamic field in magento collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, ce-1.7.0.2

I have created one magento collection like this to calculate distance from lat long.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/module')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
            $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('distance' => new Zend_Db_Expr("( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(23.0130648) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(72.4909026) ) + sin( radians(23.0130648) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )")))
            ->having('distance <10')
            ->order('distance ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);
```

But I am getting error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'.

When I print collection object Distance calculation is right. so what was the problem?

My problem is similar like this question [Issue using "having" in Magento collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5481/issue-using-having-in-magento-collection)

I am using pagination on collection, if I remove pagination class then it works perfect.
But I am unable to solve with solution provided.
Here's my pagination code.

In `_prepareLayout()` function I put this

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'pager');
          $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
          $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
          $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
          $this->getCollection()->load();
          return $this;
```

add this function also in block file

```
  public function getPagerHtml()
  {
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
  }
```

and call this in phtml file as `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can try to use `addExpressionFieldToSelect`.
You can find the method in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`.
In your case it should be something like this: (This is just an assumption, you might get some errors, but the idea is ok)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/module')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect('distance', '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(23.0130648) ) * cos( radians( {{latitude}}) ) * cos( radians( {{longitude}}) - radians(72.4909026) ) + sin( radians(23.0130648) ) * sin( radians( {{latitude}}) ) ) )', array('latitude'=>'latitude', 'longitude'=>'longitude'));
$collection->getSelect()->having('distance > 10');
```

The `addExpressionFieldToSelect` works like this:
the first parameter is the alias of the expression (virtual field name).
The second parameter is the expression. Replace the field names with placeholders wrapped arround `{{...}}`
The third parameter is the placeholder correspondence (without `{{}}`).
In your case `latitide` placeholder corresponds to `latitude` field so `{{latitude}}` will be replaced with `latitude`. Same goes for `longitude`.

**[EDIT]**
There is a problem when adding pagination to the `$collection` like this

```
$collection->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(5);
```

Here is the backtrace of the issue.
When the collection is loaded this is called `_renderLimit()`. The method looks like this

```
protected function _renderLimit()
{
    if($this->_pageSize){
        $this->_select->limitPage($this->getCurPage(), $this->_pageSize);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So this calls `getCurPage()` (see `Varien_Data_Collection` class).
`getCurPage` has an additional verification to see if the page number is not outside the max range so it calculates the total number of pages in `getLastPageNumber()`.
The problem here is that Magento resets the columns in the select for calculating the collection size. In `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSelectCountSql` there is this:

```
$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
```

By reseting the columns you end up with this sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name_here` AS `main_table` HAVING (distance < 10)
```

This is what generates the error.

I see 2 options here.

1. You override in your collection class the method `getSelectCountSql`
   and remove the column reset:

   ```
   public function getSelectCountSql()
   {
       $this->_renderFilters();

       $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
       $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
       $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
       $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
       //$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);//comment this line

       $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

       return $countSelect;
   }
   ```
2. You override the `getCurPage()` method to skip the range validation:

   ```
   public function getCurPage($displacement = 0){
       if (!empty($this->_curPage)){
           return $this->_curPage + $displacement;
       }
       return 1;
   }
   ```

**[EDIT TO EDIT]**
To avoid affecting the rest of the modules you can override the `getCurPage` method like this:

```
public function getCurPage($displacement = 0){
    if (!$this->getDirectCurPage()){//if a specific flag is not set behave as default
        return parent::getCurPage($displacement);
    }
    if (!empty($this->_curPage)){
        return $this->_curPage + $displacement;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now when you want to use your `having` method just add this to your collection

```
$collection->setDirectCurPage(1);
```

Comment: This method still not working error continue.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `having` statement and loop through the collection? Do you see a value for `distance` in the item data?

Comment: yes I can see a value of distance item if I remove having cluase.

Comment: This is strange. I tested as a proof of concept on a core collection and it works great. `$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('some_total', 'SUM({{is_active}})', array('is_active'=>'is_active'));
$collection->getSelect()->having('some_total > 1')->order('some_total ASC');` Maybe is something wrong with your module.

Comment: One thing, I am using pagination on collection so it creates issue if I remove pagination then your methods work correctly

Comment: How do you add the pagination? Maybe (most probably) that's the issue

Comment: Updated my question with pagination code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with pagination issues workaround.

Comment: If I remove column reset it will not affect any part of site just curious?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it can. I think it's safer to override `getCurPage`. I've edited again the answer with a save way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I have used your second approach for override `getCurPage()` method.

Comment: Hello what should we write instead of 'module/module'? because this is not working and giving error

Answer (score 3):

Try using this instead:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/module')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
            $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('distance' => new Zend_Db_Expr("( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(23.0130648) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude) - radians(72.4909026) ) + sin( radians(23.0130648) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )")))
            ->addAttributeHaving('distance <10')
            ->addAttributeToSort('distance', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);
```

Comment: its not working it returns null object

Answer (score 0):

You could try `where()` instead of `having()` as you don't use any `JOIN` statements:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('distance > ?', 10);
```

Comment: No it still return error Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause