# Group and/or product collection select

Tags: product, attributes, collection

Is it possible to group and/or together when creating a product collection

I have 2 attributes size and color.

I want to find products that have the following:

```
Size = 10 and Color = red
or
Size = 12 and Color = blue
or
Size = 14 and Color = green
```

It doesnt appear that the `addAttributeToFilter` method provides the possibility of doing these groups and instead allows only and or or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do that in Magento!** What were you thinking!?!

Just kidding. It helps to think about this outside of the bounds of Magento and instead in terms of Magento's underlying ORM, `Zend_Db`.

Because `Zend_Db` only supports the `orWhere` method, and has no means of grouping those OR statements, the only way I can think of doing this is by performing a `UNION` of 3 queries all with the varying clauses.

So, thinking outside of Zend even, you would then rewrite your query as separate SELECT statements rather than OR clauses:

**Statement 1**

```
...WHERE size = '10' and color = 'red';
```

**Statement 2**

```
...WHERE size = '12' and color = 'blue';
```

**Statement 3**

```
...WHERE size = '14' and color = 'green';
```

And assuming we had the raw SQL from each of these we could probably do a UNION ALL on them:

```
join(' UNION ALL ', $statements);
```

If we execute this query against the DB natively we'll get what we're looking for. So that's how we'll do it - utilizing `getSelect`:

```
$collection[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('size','10')
->addAttributeToFilter('color','red')
->getSelect();

$collection[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('size','12')
->addAttributeToFilter('color','blue')
->getSelect();

$collection[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeTofilter('size','14')
->addAttributeTofilter('color','green')
->getSelect();


$query = join(' UNION ALL ',$collection);

$result = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($query);
```

Which yields the query we're looking for:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_size`.`value` AS `size`, `at_color`.`value` AS `color` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_size` ON (`at_size`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_size`.`attribute_id` = '198') AND (`at_size`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` ON (`at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_size.value = '10') AND (at_color.value = 'red')
UNION ALL
SELECT `e`.*, `at_size`.`value` AS `size`, `at_color`.`value` AS `color` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_size` ON (`at_size`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_size`.`attribute_id` = '198') AND (`at_size`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` ON (`at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_size.value = '12') AND (at_color.value = 'blue')
UNION ALL
SELECT `e`.*, `at_size`.`value` AS `size`, `at_color`.`value` AS `color` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_size` ON (`at_size`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_size`.`attribute_id` = '198') AND (`at_size`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` ON (`at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_size.value = '14') AND (at_color.value = 'green')
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I have some notices to your answer. The result is not collection object(It means you cannot use any collection functionality). Lazy collection loading is not possible in this case. How your solution works in grids with filtering and sorting? You make one request to database but with three almost the same sub-requests.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi These are all valid points; but the OP provided no direction on how to accomplish it or where it would be used... this is a valid approach. If it were necessary to provide pagination it would obviously not be a great approach. Lazy loading is only valuable if the object is mutable further down in the application -- in your domain logic you can manage this yourself. As an aside, We're not in competition here - your answer is great and deserves merit. Not looking to attract criticism on every answer I leave here.

Comment: Yes sure. Sorry for criticism. I want your answer to stay here;). I just wrote notices for other people with such problems who are not very friendly with magento. So they should know disadvantages of the solution. Anyway only others could decide which solution will suite them better.

Comment: If you're not familiar, take a look at UNION as the "almost the same sub-requests" is how UNION is required to function. It's aggregating SELECT statements -- this is in order to form more complicated queries where joins or subqueries would cause the optimizer to take an inefficient path to solve the query. I hope this explains my approach. Thanks for your continued contribution here on magento.se!

Answer (score 1):

Standard magento functionality doesn't allow to do that. But you can always `getSelect()` and add `Zend_Statment` using `where()` method.

Also I take a look inside `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::addAttributeToFilter()` and investigated how it works.

So I can advice you to rewrite `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` and write your own method:

```
public function addAndInOrCondition($andInOrConditions)
{
    $sqlArr = array();
    foreach ($andInOrConditions as $andConditions) {
        $sqlAndArr = array();
        foreach ($andConditions as $condition) {
            $sqlAndArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition);
        }
        $sqlArr[] = '('.implode(') AND (', $sqlAndArr).')';
    }
    $conditionSql = '('.implode(') OR (', $sqlArr).')';

    if (!empty($conditionSql)) {
        $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql, null, Varien_Db_Select::TYPE_CONDITION);
    } else {
        Mage::throwException('Error message');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Now your collection will have additional method.

For this condition

```
Size = 10 and Color = red
or
Size = 12 and Color = blue
or
Size = 14 and Color = green
```

you should call `addAndInOrCondition()` like this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAndInOrCondition(
        array(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'size', 'eq' => '10'),
                array('attribute' => 'color', 'eq' => 'red'),
            ),
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'size', 'eq' => '12'),
                array('attribute' => 'price', 'eq' => 'blue'),
            ),
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'size', 'eq' => '14'),
                array('attribute' => 'price', 'eq' => 'green'),
            )
        )
    );
```

**Advantages** of this solution:

- compatibility with other collection methods
- you can use all ["Filter Condition Codes"](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)
- lazy loading
- can be used in grids with filtering, and ordering
- you can still access collection object after using this solution
- one request without sub-requests to database

**Disadvantages**

- Rewriting a model

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid to build your own where clause (which I would not always suggest). Then what you could do is to use if statements in your where.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where('if(entity_id = 16 AND type_id = "simple", TRUE, FALSE) = true')
    ->orWhere('if(entity_id = 17 AND type_id = "simple", TRUE, FALSE) = true')
    ->orWhere('if(entity_id = 18 AND type_id = "simple", TRUE, FALSE) = true');
```

One final note from me is that there looks like you could also use a mixture of the `having` function and `addExpressionAttributeToSelect`. This was taken from another stackexchange answer [How to add dynamic field in magento collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('first_where', 'if({{entity_id}} = 16 AND {{type_id}} = "simple", TRUE, FALSE)', array('entity_id', 'type_id'));
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('second_where', 'if({{entity_id}} = 17 AND {{type_id}} = "simple", TRUE, FALSE)', array('entity_id', 'type_id'));
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('third_where', 'if({{entity_id}} = 18 AND {{type_id}} = "simple", TRUE, FALSE)', array('entity_id', 'type_id'));
$collection->getSelect()->having('first_where')->orHaving('second_where')->orHaving('third_where');
```

But using this I was getting the error `Unknown column 'first_where' in 'having clause''`