# Show/Mask a admin grid different from a table

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, grid, module

I have a admin grid in admin panel, which I created using Ultimate module creator.

This Module has following columns in database table:

```
1. id
2. ref_id
3. ref_type
4. position
```

Thus, the admin grid also has the same columns.

But my requirement is to show the admin grid differently i.e

```
1. name
2. email
3. location
4. position
```

I can change the columns by visiting `{namespace}/{module_name}/Block/Adminhtml/{module_name}/Grid.php`

**But how to fill the values in newly added columns based on the old column values for each row?**

I tried like this which didn't work:

```
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'value' => 'hello' //Here I am trying to manipulate this column using  "ref_id" and "ref_type" 
    ));
```

Please help

PS: The user can edit only "position" field (*which is the only visible field*), when he/she clicks edit action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the names that appear in the grid the fix is easy. On the other hand, if you want to show in the grid a value that does not exist in your DB, it's a bit more complicated.

You said that there are 4 fields in your DB. id, ref_id, ref_type, position. These are the only 4 columns you can have in your grid. If you want more grid columns you must have either more DB fields or a joined table or a custom/expression field.

Let's take the addColumn function

```
   $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Name'), //The name that appears in the header of the grid
        'index' => 'name', //The reference to the DB field (or  custom field)
        'type' => 'text',  //The type of the column
        'value' => 'hello' //Here I am trying to manipulate the columns  "id" and "ref_id" // This you cannot do this way
    ));
```

So you are trying to get a field 'name' from the DB but that doesn't exist. Neither do email and location so where will these data be stored?

From what I understand 'name' is supposed to be an expression of 'ref_id and 'ref_type'. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957584/magento-collection-expression) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection) for starters.

EDIT:

Let's say you want a custom column 'name' that will show 'ref_id' and 'ref_type' separated by a space.

your _prepareCollection() function should look something like the following

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(`ref_id`, ' ',`ref_type`) AS name"));
    //add the above line before setCollection
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Then in your _prepareColumns() function add

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Name'),
    'index' => 'name', //this index points to the column you created in prepareCollection
    'type' => 'text',
));
```

Comment: I don't know how to assign a value to each row of the new columns. I mean to which attribute should I add? and how? I am showing `value` attribute just for example. I am not sure whether I should use `value` attribute or not. Lets say `value` attribute is right attribute. Then How should I use `ref_id` and `ref_name` of that row to manipulate the value? I am looking for something like this: `'attributeName' : if($refName == "somename"){ return $this->getId($refId)->getName()}else{return "none"; }`. I hope you got my point now..

Comment: There is no way to do this in your prepareColumn function. You have to add a custom field to your collection in the prepareCollection function. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks.. I hadn't thought about `_prepareCollection()` :)

Comment: You're welcome.