# using calculated value in custom sort

Tags: attributes, catalog, sort

I've been trying to apply this post:

[How to add dynamic field in magento collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection/6310#6310)

to my own simple scenario.

I have implemented a rewrite of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
to handle a custom sort option in catalog view.

I need to pull two attributes (msrp and special_price) do some math with them to create a 'virtual' field upon which to sort.

```
class NAMESPACE_MODULE_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{


public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
if ($attribute == 'rebate' && $storeId != 0) {
        $this->addPriceData();
        $this->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array(
                    'attribute' => 'special_price_type',
                    'value'     => array('1340', '1339')
                )
            )
        );
        $this->addAttributeToSelect(
            array('special_price', 'msrp')
        );

        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'ratio',
            "[pseudocode: ( 1 - (mrsp - special_price))*100 ]"

        ); //select
        $this->getSelect()->order("ratio {$dir}");

        return $this;
    }
```

Struggling to understand how to manipulate those values in addExpressionAttributeToSelect. Nor am I clear whether those values are even exposed at this point. 
I would assume so because of:

```
   $this->addAttributeToSelect(
            array('special_price', 'msrp')
        );
```

However dropping a breakpoint there and stepping through the code, I can't find them anywhere in the instantiated object.

Any guidance welcome!

Comment: After studying a little bit more addAttributeToSelect

I really feel like  

`$this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
                'ratio',
               
                '( ( 1 - ( {{msrp}} - {{special_price}}))*100 )',
                array(
                    'special_price'=>'special_price',
                    'msrp'=>'msrp',
                )
            ); //`

Should be giving me the result i need. I'm no longer getting SQL errors this way. But sorting does appear to be default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unrelated issue was causing interference. Working code below.

```
 if ($attribute == 'rebate' && $storeId != 0) {
        $this->addPriceData();
        $this->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array(
                    'attribute' => 'special_price_type',
                    'value'     => array('1340', '1339')
                )
            )
        );
        $this->addAttributeToSelect(array(
            'msrp',
            'price',
            'special_price'
        ));
        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'ratio',
            '(ROUND( ( 1 - ( {{price}} - {{special_price}} ) )*100 ))',
            array(
                'special_price' => 'special_price',
                'price'         => 'price',
            )
        ); //
        $this->getSelect()->order("ratio {$dir}");
        return $this;
    }
```