# Use having clause in Magento grid

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, collection, grid

Iam trying build a grid in Magento , where i need to  calculate days between two dates so that i can filter days.But i could not get it right with ,

Following is the piece of collection code in grid .

preparecollection

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('days' => new Zend_Db_Expr ('datediff(main_table.support_end_date,now())')));


$collection->getSelect()->having('days <= ?', '60');
```

Prepare columns

```
$this->addColumn('days', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('tp_adminpurchase')->__('Days '),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'days',
            'filter_index' => 'days',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterDays'),
        ));


  protected function _filterDays($collection, $column) {
        $condition = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
        $collection->getSelect()->having('days <= ?', '60');
          return $countSelect;
    }
```

In collection.php , i have this

```
public function getSelectCountSql() {
        $this->_renderFilters();

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->columns('datediff(main_table.support_end_date,current_date) AS days');

    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

    return $countSelect;
    }
```

My issues are

1) Filter on days is not pulling proper records
2) Count on the grid is showing incorrect

I have refferred below issues but no luck
[How to add dynamic field in magento collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection)

[Issue using "having" in Magento collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5481/issue-using-having-in-magento-collection)

Could any one help in sorting this out, where iam going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could able to fix it on my own, it would be help full for others

In Grid.php, i have added following line to get calculated days

```
 
protected function _prepareCollection() 
{  
  $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('days' => new 
  Zend_Db_Expr('datediff(main_table.support_end_date,now())'))); 

 }

protected function _prepareColumns() 
{
 $this->addColumn('days', array(
             'header' => Mage::helper('tp_adminpurchase')->__('Expire Days '),
             'align' => 'left',
             'index' => 'days',
             'filter_index' => 'days',
             'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterDays'),
         ));

 }



protected function _filterDays($collection, $column)
{
  $condition = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
  $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->having('days = ?', $condition);
         return $this;

}
```

To fix ,the count issue in grid i have this function in my Collection.php  class

```
  public function getSize() {
        if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {

            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
        }
        return intval($this->_totalRecords);
    }
```

Now i have working grid which shows the calculated days which can also be filtered

Answer (score 3):

First of all `$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);` means it will reset `HAVING` from your collection. That means it will remove the having clause. And Its not what you want. You may want to add it to the collection (`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php->_getSelectCountSql()` here.)

But the main culprit it the `getSize()` method which exists in `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` file.

> I tried the above solution mentioned by @bharat but that didnt work.

Now i did the below.

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        //$sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $sql = $this->getSelect();
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

or if you want to keep the original code for performance for any other cases

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {

        if($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP) OR $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING))
        {
            $sql = $this->getSelect();
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
        }
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

Check i am not even using the `getSelectCountSql()`. I am just reading the whole **SQL QUERY** and **fetching all data** and **return the count** of it. That's all.